# Style sheets priority order

Tags: css, stylesheet

If I have the following style sheets:

```
user important declarations
user normal declarations
author normal declarations
user agent declarations
author important declarations
```

and need to apply them from highest priority to lowest priority, in which order should I use them?

Comment: Can there not be a `user agent important declaration` in style sheet? If there is one I believe it will have highest priority.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The correct order of precedence is, from least important to most important:

1. User Agent
2. User Normal
3. Author Normal
4. Author Important
5. User Important

As defined in the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/cascade.html#cascading-order)

Comment: Just for everyone's cause, the order is from least priority -> highest priority. I checked out the specification and to quote: "Sort according to importance (normal or important) ". I hope this helps, especially for 70-480 exam takers.

Comment: I did say in my answer "from least important to most important" ;)

Comment: @KevinIsNowOnline You are absolutly correct, it helps especially for 70-480 exam takers. Thanks for the comment

Comment: Can there not be a 6th `user agent important declaration` option when thinking about style sheets? If there is one I believe it will have highest priority. Or may be browsers might *never* be doing so as that style will never be overridable as it will be hard coded in browser code itself. Isn't it?

Answer (score 10):

CSS declarations are applied in this order (from lowest to highest priority):

1. user agent declarations (the default styles your browser applies to
   elements)
2. user normal declarations (a user's own stylesheet if they're using
   one)
3. author normal declarations (this is your normal stylesheet)
4. author important declarations (anything your mark important)
5. user important declarations (any important styles from the user's
   stylesheet)

Comment: This is also incorrect in the order...should be reversed

Comment: Thanks for explanations of every style

Comment: I want a deep explanations with example to understand these style sheet please provide me any link where I can understand all these.

Answer (score 0):

Below content is taken from **[here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/#Style_sheet_cascade_order)**.

Style property can appear in any number of style sheets, and several times inside a single style sheet. Therefore, order of applying the rules is very important. This is called the "cascade" order. According to CSS2 spec, the cascade order is (from low to high):

1. Browser declarations
2. User normal declarations
3. Author normal declarations
4. Author important declarations
5. User important declarations

a) The browser declarations are least important;
b) User overrides the author only if the declaration was marked as important.
 
c) Declarations with the same order will be sorted by **[specificity](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/#Specificity)** and then the order they are specified.
 
d) The HTML visual attributes are translated to matching CSS declarations.
 
e) They are treated as author rules with low priority.