# How is a CSS rule evaluated, with respect to duplicate (fallback) attributes?

Tags: css, fallback

How do web browsers interprete **duplicate attributes** in a CSS Rule?
Here an example what is meant:

```
body
{
    background-color:red;
    background-color:blue;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,255,1);
}
```

Important aspect to me:

1. Is is valid to define a attribute multiple times?
2. Is the rule evaluated so that the value of the attribute is set to  the last value (*last - as in appearing later in the rule's text*) encountered is used? 
   By experimenting I see that in the example above above `rgba(0,0,255,1)` is used, but is this coincidence or defined?
3. What happens if a value is not understood by the browser? Will it "fallback" to the last value seen before, still understood **or** become *undefined* because of the not understood last value?

   For instance if a browser would not support `rgba(r,g,b)`, but instead `red` and `blue`. would the background-color then be set to `blue` as it was the last value (sort of a fallback), or will it fail completely?
4. (Assuming there is a defined behaviour to use the last "understood" value), will this be valid for all understood attributes? (<del>Microsoft IE6</del> *Apple's Safari Browser* for instance is not implementing all `touch-action` values , only `auto` and `manipulation`, could I hence do the following:

```
body
{
    /* first set to manipulation, to at*/
    /* least disable double-tap-zoom on iOS Safari*/
    touch-action:manipulation;
    /* then set it to the actually desired */
    /* value of pan-y, supported by other */
    /* modern browsers */
    touch-action:pan-y;
}
```

Comment: 1. Yes, 2. Yes, and it is explicitly specified this way, 3. falls back to the last understood value, so `blue` in this example, 4. Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right on your assumptions. According to MDN: CSS If a browser encounters a declaration or rule it doesn't understand, it just skips it completely without applying it or throwing an error.

Read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Cross_browser_testing/HTML_and_CSS

Answer (score 1):

As your question is understood by me, I will try to give you a broader picture and will try to explain every important aspect mentioned by you.

1. There is no point in creating same rule and just changing its value over and over. As CSS reads from top to bottom in a tag or class i.e; body{} in above case, each time it reads same rule in the pack, it re-instantiate the rule until explicitly defined using '!important' at the end of the rule.
2. Yes its working is as simple as you stated for your second aspect and its defined.
3. According to MDN: CSS If a browser encounters a rule it doesn't understand, it will skip it and goes on further.

Comment: 1. depends on how it's written. If you use for example classes and use a class multiple times but with another identifier before it, it does make sense to re-use it. So it really matters what he means with "define an attribute multiple times".

Answer (score 1):

A CSS rule is written and its parts named, for example:

```
at-rule optional (conditions) {
  /* rule */
  /* begins with a selector list */
  selector1, selector2 /* {
    /* block rule */
    property1: valueA;
    property2: value2;
    property1: valueB;
  }
  /* end of rule */
}
```

- at-rule like `@media <media-query-list>` must apply or else everything inside is ignored (may apply 2s later or before if user resizes its viewport for example). If it's invalid, it won't ever be applied
- if any selector in the selector list is invalid in this browser, the whole rule is ignored
- for each property, the last value that was understood by the browser is applied. It doesn't matter if it's in the same rule or different ones, in different stylesheets, etc. Specificity of selectors apply (at-rules don't have any added specificity) so the selector of the last valid declaration encountered must have higher or equal specificity than the second to last one or else it won't apply.

So:

1. It is valid to define a CSS property multiple times
2. Yes
3. See above (you've a typo: `rgb(r, g, b)` and `rgba(r, g, b, a)` are understood by modern browsers but not `rgba(r, g, b)`)
4. Yep

EDIT: this is for author stylesheets (you and me are the authors, being web developers/designers) and there's another set of priorities when you consider [user agent stylesheets, user stylesheets and `!important`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13638067/137626)  (user always have the last word on the web :p).