# Cannot Override User Agent Stylesheet

Tags: html, css, user-agent

Is it possible to overwrite the user agent styles for auto-filled input fields?

I have tried selectors of every specificity, and even the nuclear inline-!important style does not override it.

In the chrome devtools, it shows the user agent stylesheet as being overridden, but it still ends up on top. Is it possible to overwrite this, or should I bite the bullet and accept that my login page will be sullied with white-background inputs?

[A picture of the computed styles.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMokE.jpg)

Comment: Hi and welcome. please modify your question after reading this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Style sheets priority order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638038/style-sheets-priority-order)